# Fresh install of Ubuntu, Virtual box no longer works

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, virtualbox

Recently upgraded Ubuntu via a fresh install of 16.04 Lts 64bit, kept home folder contents into new installation, but now Virtual Box (5.0.40) has problems, when I try to start a machine from saved state (Ubuntu 14.04 32bit) - I get error message:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Ubuntu 14.04 32bit
Failed to load unit 'cpum' (VERR_SSM_FIELD_OUT_OF_BOUNDS).
```

Result Code:

```
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
```

Component:

```
ConsoleWrap
```

Interface:

```
IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

Does anyone know of a solution? Thanks

Comment: A good possible solution might be to download the current version of VirtualBox - 5.1.24  [VirtualBox Downloads](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads)

Comment: `Failed to load unit 'cpum' (VERR_SSM_FIELD_OUT_OF_BOUNDS).
` seems to me like a problem between 64bit and 32bit system!

Comment: Charles Green, thanks for your comment, although I'm not sure if there would be any issue getting a version not available in the ubuntu repository, as according to synaptic I have the most recent available..?

Comment: derHugo, thanks for your idea, but I've run 32bit virtual machine on my previous 64bit installation, so I know it should normally run fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you're running identical releases of VirtualBox, according to this thread on Virtualbox.org: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=77554

You'll need to delete the saved state of your VM, as the change to the host OS is enough to cause the problem you describe with the VM.

That said, my own experience suggests that just moving between VirtualBox versions can cause problems with VM saved states. Again, the solution is to delete the saved state of the VM.

Rich

Comment: Rich, thank you, discarding the saved state restored the machine to working order..!